# dynamic dropdown list - return value

Tags: excel

Ive got a spreadsheet which has 3 columns. These are name, age, value

I want to create an incell dropdown list based on unique values in the "name" column. There could be two cells in the "name" column with "John" in them for example. i.e. duplicates

When "John" is selected in a dropdown I want to create another dynamically created dropdown that shows only the age's for the entries. For example, if there were two rows with "John" in the name column then the other dropdown should show the age values for each of these only. Based on the two selections id like to show whatever's in the value column.

Do you think i need to use macros to achieve this?

To complicate matters the amount of rows in the list may change over time and therefore the blank names will need to be removed. The 'ignore blanks' when creating the incell dropdown does nothing and they are still shown in the list.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: can you elaborate this - "if there were two rows with "John" in the name column then the other dropdown should show the age values for each of these only"

Comment: In the "Name" column there could be two cells (rows) with duplicate entries. In the post i gave an example of "John".

Comment: still dont get it

Comment: There are 3 columns. The first column is an unknown length and may contain duplicates. I need to create an in cell dropdown list of all the unique values. Then, when one of these values is selected i need to create a second in cell dropdown list. The values for that list need to be taken from the second column. Does that help?

Comment: I'm similarly a bit confused. To clarify, do you mean that if your list showed:

Name-Age-Val
John-14-4
Bill-34-2
Sue-21-3
John-16-5
And "John" was selected in the first drop down, then the second drop down would show both 14 and 16? If so I believe I have a solution. Please clarify.

Comment: You clarified just before I posted, one moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description I think you are creating list validated drop down cells. The lists can be subsets of an initial database. An example of such a database might look like:

[image: Initial List]

With the validated drop downs adjacent like:

[image: With Drop Downs]

This can be achieved in a few steps.

**1)** Create a subset of all of the unique names in a helper column, I will do this in J.

```
=IFERROR(IF(NOT(INDEX($A$2:$A$20,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($J$1:J1,$A$2:$A$20),0,0),0))=""),INDEX($A$2:$A$20,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($J$1:J1,$A$2:$A$20),0,0),0)),NA()),"")
```

The range I am testing for uniques only extends to A20 but you could take this as far as you like.

**2)** Since you are doing this with validation lists that a user must select, you should probably alphabetize them. I do this in the next column over K.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(INDIRECT("J1:J"&SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(J:J)>0))+1),MATCH(ROWS($J$2:J2),COUNTIF(INDIRECT("J1:J"&SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(J:J)>0))+1),"<="&INDIRECT("J1:J"&SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(J:J)>0))+1)),0)),"")
```

This formula is an array formula and must be entered with ***ctrl+shift+enter*** for the first cell and then you can fill down. In a near by cell let's keep track of the complete range occupied by meaningful names used to make our alphabetized list (no blanks). Enter the following:

```
="K2:K"&SUMPRODUCT(--(LEN(J:J)>0))+1
```

Note that this is assuming my uniques are in column J. If you put them elsewhere you will need to modify this.

**3)** At this point we can make our first validated drop down. I'm using excel 2016 so I select the cell where I want the drop down (in my case E2) and then go to Data -> Validation. Under this I choose Allow: List; and Source: I enter the following:

```
=INDIRECT($K$1)
```

As K1 is the cell where I am keeping track of the range of useful and alphabetized uniques. Example:[image: Validation]

Now back on the main sheet I have a drop down in E2 featuring that list. Next let's build the subset of useful ages.

**4)** In a new helper range (for me 'M2:M10') enter the following:

```
=IFERROR(SUM(LARGE(IF(($A$2:$A$20=$E$2)*ROW($A$2:$A$20),$B$2:$B$20,""),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$20,"="&$E$2)-ROW()+ROW($M$2))),"")
```

This is another array formula and must be submitted with ***ctrl+shift+enter***, but in contrast the other array formula you must enter this for the whole range at once, I just selected a small number of cells because I know I won't have more than a few ages. If you suspect you will have more make this range large.

In the same fashion as the names lets track the range of useful ages in a nearby cell (I chose N1).

```
="M2:M"&COUNTIF((M:M),">0")+1
```

**5)** Make the next validated drop down. Select a cell (I picked F2) and again Data->Validation, choose a list and now use the age source:

```
=INDIRECT($N$1)
```

**6)** Getting the value that corresponds to the individual with that age is easy now. In the next cell over from enter:

```
=SUM(IF((A2:A20=E2)*(B2:B20=F2),C2:C20))
```

There you have it. An example of what my completed sheet looks like is here:

[image: Completely Functional]

One last thing to mention. When you do this and toggle to a new name, it will not reset the age drop down automatically. So to make this appear reset, you can use some clever conditional formatting. I formatted F2 & G2 with the following rule and set the font color to white:

[image: Conditional Format]

So while the value in each of those cells doesn't reset when a drop down with higher precedence is changed it appears to blank out forcing the user to pick a new age from that drop down.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much. For some odd reason getting the uniques from the first column worked fine but i couldn't get the second one working. Just ended up doing a static dropdown, a helper column, vlookup and conditional formatting if no value found.

Comment: This code is pretty slow. Any way of speeding it up? Happy to use a macro i suppose